# AVAudioPlayer Play/Pause/Stop local audio file on three different buttons

Tags: objective-c, avaudioplayer

I want to play/pause/stop local audio file. Buttons for all functionalities are different. Check attached screenshot for reference.

[image]

Below is my click events,

```
-(IBAction)click_Play:(id)sender {
        NSString *path;
        NSURL *url;

        //where you are about to add sound
        AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
        [audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];

        path =[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MySong" ofType:@"mp3"];
        url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

        player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:NULL];
        [player setVolume:1.0];
        [player prepareToPlay];
        [player play];

}

-(IBAction)click_Pause:(id)sender {
    [player pause];
}

-(IBAction)click_Stop:(id)sender {
    [player stop];
}
```

Here, I am facing issue in pause functionality. After pausing the audio when I click on play button again. It start playing from starting and not at the point where I pause it. Any solution?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code to this:

```
-(IBAction)click_Play:(id)sender {
    if (!player)
    {
        NSString *path;
        NSURL *url;

        //where you are about to add sound
        AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
        [audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];

        path =[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MySong" ofType:@"mp3"];
        url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

        player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:NULL];
        [player setVolume:1.0];
        [player prepareToPlay];
        [player play];
    }
    else {
        [player play];
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks a lot!. Works perfect! (Y)

Answer (score 1):

Don't create instance of `AVAudioSession` and `AVAudioPlayer` again and again in play button action. So, keep it simple, create instance of `AVAudioSession` and `AVAudioPlayer` in `viewDidLoad`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *path;
    NSURL *url;

    //where you are about to add sound
    AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    [audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];

    path =[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MySong" ofType:@"mp3"];
    url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

    player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:NULL];
    [player setVolume:1.0];
    [player prepareToPlay];
} 

-(IBAction)click_Play:(id)sender {
    [player play];
}

-(IBAction)click_Pause:(id)sender {
    [player pause];
}

-(IBAction)click_Stop:(id)sender {
    [player stop];
}
```

**Edit:**
Call this method when you what to change track. I'll never recommend to create instance of object again and again

```
-(void)changeTrackWithPath:(NSString *)path{
    AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [[AVPlayerItem alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]];
    [player replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
    [player play];
}
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your help. But the code which I added in my question is just an example. My audio will be changed every time as per user's selection. So I could not add this code in viewDidLoad.

Comment: @Gati You can call this method with path of the track to change the track

Comment: Hey I am getting error for this method call, replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104167/discussion-between-vineet-choudhary-and-gati).